# How to logout from google plus account in google plus integration in android

Tags: android, google-plus, logout

I did following work but it is not working after logout it quickly again login in app

```
private void signOutFromGplus() {

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

        // clearCookies();

        Plus.AccountApi
                .clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);

        .mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

        .mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working means logout option is not working or login is not working ? check https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#sign_out_the_user

Comment: it is signout one time  and again automatically login and there is no problem with login

Answer (score 2):

Assign you variable in this class (Advantage of using this class is that this class starts when application is launched and you can access this anywhere in app ) as : 
**MyApplication.class**

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
public class MyApplication extends Application {
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private GoogleSignInOptions gso;
public AppCompatActivity activity;
public GoogleSignInOptions getGoogleSignInOptions(){
    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    return gso;
}
public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient(AppCompatActivity activity, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener listener){
    this.activity = activity;
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this.activity, listener)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, getGoogleSignInOptions())
            .build();
    return mGoogleApiClient;
}
}
```

**In Login Activity**

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                //hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    gso = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getGoogleSignInOptions();
    mGoogleApiClient = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getGoogleApiClient(LoginActivity.this, this);
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}
```

**In Second Activity where you want to logout**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mGoogleApiClient = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getGoogleApiClient(HomeActivity.this, this);

btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}
```

**In your app-level build.gradle file, declare Google Play Services as a dependency:**

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

}

**Let MyApplication class extends the default Application class. Also, open the Manifest file and add this line of code in application element.**

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be an old question but I want to clear here that most probably the freshers who had made the Google login for the first time. They might be facing issue in auto login of Google account after calling the below method.

```
private void signOutFromGplus() {

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

        // clearCookies();

        Plus.AccountApi
                .clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);

        .mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

        .mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

Solution: Make sure that your mGoogleApiClient is not disconnected already somewhere. So why the reason it is not entering into this if loop.

Most probably in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `Sign-out` and `Revoke`.  It seems you want to disconnect the user from the app, so the user is prompted again for login the next time.  If this is the case, please try the following (for more details refer to [Google+ Sign-in for Android](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#revoking_access_tokens_and_disconnecting_the_app)):

```
// Prior to disconnecting, run clearDefaultAccount().
Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

  onResult(Status status) {
    // mGoogleApiClient is now disconnected and access has been revoked.
    // Trigger app logic to comply with the developer policies
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Google's instructions say to call connect() immediately after disconnect(), I had the same problem as you in doing so - the user is logged in again without any interaction.

In the end I simply ignored the instructions and removed that call to connect() from my code. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void googlePlusLogout() {

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {    
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);    
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();    
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();    
        }    
    }
```

Try to call this method on button click.